# Combining 2 events on one element click Jquery

Tags: jquery

Currently I have a function that works by clicking one button to add a set of fields and one to remove them all for a form in adding attendees.

I'm having difficulties in adding the 3 lines in the white block that increments the number of attendees the same time the click is called and a set of fields is added to fill out.

I've tried creating a callback after

```
 next.slideDown('slow'); to next.slideDown('slow', function(){ ... });
```

but to no success.

How would i combine these to events to one click?

http://jsfiddle.net/h76KR/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#div2, #div3, #div4').hide();
    $('#add').click(function () {
        var curr = $(".question:visible");
        var next = curr.next(".question");
        next.slideDown('slow');
```

var theTotal = 0;

theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());

$('.noOfAttendees').text(Total number of attendees from your firm: "+theTotal");

```
    });
    $('#remove').click(function () {
        var prev = $(".question:visible");
        var remove = prev.next(".question");
        remove.slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't get your question. You have 2 events here: "click on add button" and "click on remove button". Do you want to combine these into one?

Comment: _"the 3 lines in the white block"_ - What white block?

Comment: If you want a unique button, wich div(s) are you expecting to show/hide on click; because a toggle method (with one button) will only work to show /hide the second fieldset in your example

Comment: Sorry, I've now reformatted part of the question with the 3 lines (they got included in the rest of the code on save.) The remove function i want left as a separate function, but resides next to the first and there to help explain the scenario.

Comment: Actually it looks like somebody else edited your question to move those lines into the rest of your code. Anyway, can't you just set the total to the number of visible items: `$(".question:visible").length` - or you can do this `$('.noOfAttendees').text('Total number of attendees from your firm: ' + (curr.length + 1));` (updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h76KR/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you request would be something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/h76KR/3/

With a

```
var numEmployees = 1;
```

that you just increment and decrease as necessary, and then using

```
function updateEmployees(){
     $(".noOfAttendees").html("There are "+numEmployees+" Attendees");   
}
```

to update the box.

---

Incidentally it would probably be much nicer to keep an empty, hidden, div with your employee information that you clone. You can then have infinite of such clones, instead of just four. Taking your example, try doing this:

```
var employeeDiv = $("#div1").clone();
$("#div1").append(employeeDiv);
```

and work from there.

Comment: Not sure if this is what he want, he specify that he want only one click event so assuming he want only one button... or not

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've found that I didn't need to combine it into a function, I've created the following below that works and resets it back to 1 on clicking the remove button. If anyone knows of a more efficient way of doing this please let me know, it's always good to improve ones logic and method.

http://jsfiddle.net/nYHNk/1/

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#div2, #div3, #div4').hide();
$('#add').click(function(){
     //code
    var curr = $(".question:visible");
    var next = curr.next(".question");
    next.show();

});

$('#remove').click(function(){
    var prev = $(".question:visible");
    var remove = prev.next(".question");
    remove.hide();
});    
});

var oneAtt = 1;
var theTotal = 1;
$('#add').click(function(){
theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());
$('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);        
});

$('.total').text("Total: "+theTotal);        

$('#remove').click(function (){
    theTotal = oneAtt;
   $('.total').text("Total: "+oneAtt); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn, I didn't see you code until just after I've posted this, that would be alot more efficient.